# Rails overriding active record setter in a relation

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I want to override the `<<` setter in my relation. For example, given:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups

  def readers
    groups.find_by(name: 'readers').users
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
end

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, through :group_membership
end
```

I want to do something like

```
someLibrary.readers << user1
```

and some additional things to happen after this.

The code should look something like:

```
def <<(objects)
  super objects
  #do other things here
end
```

Where should it be? I guess in `Group`, like:

```
class Group
  ...
  def users<<(objects)
    super objects
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

but I only want to do it when I'm invoking `<<` on readers.

I want to know if there is a way to know whether I'm invoking `<<` on a group users relationship, or whether I have access to group object when I'm invoking `<<` method on group users through the relationship.

I want to do it because it looks nice. The easiest way would be to define separate method to set readers (and be more explicit), but I want to know if it is possible in activerecord or in ruby.

edit:

Yeah I know that overriding core methods is bad thing and people go to hell for that, yada yada yada.

I'm just curious how it's done. Like, for learning purposes.

Besides the aim is just to override the `<<` method on that particular relation so probable there might be some justification why someone might want to do it.

Comment: What is `someLibrary.readers.class` in your version of `AR`?

Comment: IMHO it is a terrible idea to override Rails methods. Why don't you add a new method with a name that reflects what it really does? What do you try to achieve by overriding a Rails core method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory disclaimer:

> I **do not recommend that you do this**, in 'important' code. Changing the behaviour of methods like this will confuse the hell out of other developers (as well as your future self), and lead to all sorts of unintended behavioural changes!
>
> But assuming that this is 'just for fun'...

Based on the information above, `someLibrary.readers` returns a collection of `User` records. So all we need to do is add the desired behaviour to that class.

*Normally* you can do this by just defining a class method, in one of two ways:

```
class User
  def self.foo
    puts 'this works!'
  end

  class << self
    def bar
      puts 'this works too!'
    end
  end
end
```

With the above in place, you can call the methods like:

```
someLibrary.readers.foo
someLibrary.readers.bar
```

...However, there is some rails black magic going on under the hood here. `someLibrary.readers` is actually an instance of `User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, and the above methods are being picked up dynamically and appended to `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`.

Because of this *dynamic* method definition, it is not possible to override existing Rails methods (such as `<<`) in this manner. Instead, we'll need to monkey-patch the `User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` class directly:

```
class User
  class ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
    def <<(objects)
      super(objects)
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

If you're looking for a better way of doing this however, I'd recommend using a **service object** design pattern. You can then encapsulate any more complex/custom logic relating to creating/updating/deleting users, libraries, etc. in a clean and isolated abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

The more established way to do this...

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_one :reader_group -> {groups.find_by(name: 'readers')}
  has_many :readers, through: :reader_group, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

And that's it.  You can now do

```
my_library.readers << another_user
```